# How to restrict access to Ethernet ports outside of physical permiter

Tags: security, ethernet, webcam, rj-45, power-over-ethernet

I have several PoE IP webcams installed on my house.  Each mounting point has only one wire going to it: the Cat6 with 8P8C plug at the end, which both powers and communicates with the camera.

I would like to ensure that if any device other than the known camera is connected to the port, the attacker won't be able to access the network.  What's the best way to do that?  I would prefer the solution to be as much hands-off as possible.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Place the cameras and the machine monitoring them on a separate VLAN. They would then be completely shielded from the rest of the network no matter what is attached to the cables leading to a camera.

Requires: Managed switch supporting VLAN feature.

Note: You may also want to disable switch login access from the camera VLAN to increase security.

Edit: As suggested by Keltari, all cameras can still be accessed. You could assign each camera one VLAN and then let the monitoring machine be part of all. Then they would have to hack the machine to get access to the rest of the cameras.

Comment: This would still allow an attacker to the camera's network though.  You could enable [MAC address filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_filtering), but that isnt much of a deterrent.

Comment: What if I want to access the machine monitoring it remotely?  Do I have to have two NICs in it or can I configure the single NIC to be in several VLANs (as you can tell, I don't have experience with managed switches).  The machine is Linux, if it matters.

Comment: @Keltari: I already use MAC address filtering (DHCP level), and I assume the VLAN routers can enforce it on their level too.  However, it's not that difficult for the attacker to change the MAC address on his/her device.

Comment: @Rom As I said, its not much of a deterrent.

Comment: It really comes down to how secure you *need* to be, versus the effort you want to put out.  Always assume if someone has physical access to a device, they have complete access.  I wouldnt go as far as putting each camera on a separate VLAN, but that depends on you.